# Usar valor de $_SESSION em função

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho essa função Javascript abaixo, onde quero mudar o `display` de um link caso o valor de uma variável de sessão seja igual a determinado valor.

Porém, dessa forma que eu fiz, não está dando certo, ainda me confundo muito ao usar Javascript e PHP.

Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?

E seria possível fazer isso usando apenas PHP ao usuário carregar a página?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    document.onload=function mostraCampominha() {
      var select = <?php echo $_SESSION['aprovado']?>;
      var txt = document.getElementById("minha");
      txt.style.display = (select.value == 'sim') 
          ? "block"
          : "none";    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Qual o valor de $_SESSION['aprovado']? Pelo restante do seu código parece ser um objeto... Se for, tenta usar o json_encode no echo e no javascript você faz um JSON.parse nesse valor: var select = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['aprovado'])?>");

Comment: @JuniorNunes O valor de `$_SESSION['aprovado']` seria ou `sim` ou `não`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente é a falta de aspas:

```
var select = <?php echo $_SESSION['aprovado']?>;
```

**Deveria ser:**

```
var select = "<?php echo $_SESSION['aprovado']?>";
```

E um detalhe citado pelo @JuniorNunes é que isto esta errado `select.value == 'sim'`, o `select` deverá retornar uma string, deve ficar assim:

```
txt.style.display = select == 'sim' ? "block" : "none";
```

Outro detalhe muito importante, isto esta errado:

```
document.onload=function mostraCampominha() {
```

O correto é:

```
window.onload=function mostraCampominha() {
```

### Sobre as aspas

Sem as aspas provavelmente a página esta sendo gerada assim depois que é baixada pelo navegador:

```
var select = sim;
```

Ou

```
var select = não;
```

No caso do primeiro, o JavaScript irá procurar uma variável chamada `sim` ou `não`, como provavelmente não existe ele setar o `var select` como `undefined`, provavelmente o seu console do navegador deve estar emitindo este erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: não is not defined

Comment: Eu coloquei as aspas mas ainda continua não mostrando link quando o valor é igual a ´sim´

Comment: @ArthurOliveira faça isso `var_dump($_SESSION['aprovado']);` fora da tag `<script>`, copia o resultado e me manda.

Comment: @JuniorNunes obrigado, era isso mesmo que faltava, editei a resposta e lhe citei.

Comment: O var_dump retorna isso `string(3) "sim"` . Eu fiz essas mudanças, porém ainda não está funcionando

Comment: @ArthurOliveira o problema era o `select.value == "sim"` também, eu ajustei a resposta para isto `txt.style.display = select == 'sim' ? "block" : "none";`

Comment: Mesmo com essa mudança ainda continua não dando certo, eu tentei também usando o JSON igual o Junior disse, mas não da certo!

Comment: Entra no chat por favor, [vamos continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69755/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-arthur-oliveira).